# Will .Net framework 4.8 support Microsoft enterprise library v6.0?

Tags: enterprise-library, .net-4.8

Since some of our applications are written in .Net framework 2.0 & 4.5, We've plan to migrate our applications to .Net framework 4.8 and we have used MS enterprise library v3.0 & v5.0 and would like to uplift to enterprise library v6.0 Before going to migrate, need to know will the latest .Net framework 4.8 support enterprise library v6.0.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [port of Enterprise Library 6.0](https://github.com/Chavoshi/EnterpriseLibrary.NetCore) that is supports .Net Core and .Net Standard 2.0.
I have not used that yet, so I cannot tell anything about its quality but based on the Nuget stats it seems tell that people are using these packages.

Also the [original Microsoft Enterprise Library source code](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/enterprise-library) was published on GitHub so you could recompile the whole project using updated references, not sure how much effort would that cost.